# Valid HTTPS certificate for dotnet development on localhost - Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, ssl, .net-core, openssl

I'm trying to serve a .NET application over HTTPS on Ubuntu 20.04. I've tried using the `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` command, but it doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu. I've also tried generating my own certificates using OpenSSL, but I'm having trouble getting them to be trusted. Can anyone help me figure out how to create a trusted HTTPS certificate for my .NET app on Ubuntu?"

Answer (score 1):

Option "--trust" does not work on any flavor of Linux because of different implementations of security infrastructure. In the document https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32842 you can find needed information.
In the case of Ubuntu you can run the script below:

```
# Setup Firefox
echo "{
    \"policies\": {
        \"Certificates\": {
            \"Install\": [
                \"aspnetcore-localhost-https.crt\"
            ]
        }
    }
}" > policies.json

dotnet dev-certs https -ep localhost.crt --format PEM

sudo mv policies.json /usr/lib/firefox/distribution/
mkdir -p ~/.mozilla/certificates
cp localhost.crt ~/.mozilla/certificates/aspnetcore-localhost-https.crt

# Trust Edge/Chrome
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n localhost -i ./localhost.crt
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n localhost -i ./localhost.crt

# Trust dotnet-to-dotnet (.pem extension is important here)
sudo cp localhost.crt /usr/lib/ssl/certs/aspnetcore-https-localhost.pem

# Cleanup
rm localhost.crt
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).